# Making a dynamic site cache able? PHP

Tags: php, caching, dynamic

i'm wondering to generate cache pages of my website to avoid same queries again and again. there's almost 80% of queries fetching data that is almost not change able in near future (*if cache system doesn't effected of its changing*).

is there any good cache library or script which i should use? or is there any conditions to use cache system? Site pages are simple developed in `html`, `js`, `css` and no `smarty` template etc. please advise me in this regard. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at memcached.

Comment: does this suit to sharing hosting environment ?

Comment: Depends on the service, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is popular caching framework. It is an open-source, networked, in-memory, key-value data store that can be used as a drop-in caching backend for your Drupal or WordPress website. 
You can store data as key value in redis, so it is very easy to integrate in your application. For more information look [Redis as a Caching Backend](https://pantheon.io/docs/articles/sites/redis-as-a-caching-backend/). It may be helpful to you.

Comment: thank you for replying, it seems like it's only for drupal or wordpress? is it able to implement on fully custom developed php site ?

Comment: Yes it is! I am not php developer but I have used it in my .net application. Have a look at this [How to Use Redis with PHP using PhpRedis with Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/phpredis/)

Comment: for that i have to make all of my sql queries go through the `Redis`'s functions. right ?